# How to iterate n times using stream in java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

Using the basic for-loop, I have written the following :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      int id = list.get(i).getId();
      ResponseEntity<Response> response = getDetail(id);  //some method call
     Integer totalUser = response.getBody().getData();
     map.put(list.get(i).getUser , totalUser);
}
```

But I want to write this in a better way using stream in java 8.

Comment: So basically for each entry in the list you want to retrieve the details by it's id?

Comment: "But I want to write this in a better way using stream in java 8." why do you think it would be better? Which aspect you hope to improve?

Comment: There's two lists in this code, `list` and `dataList`, are they the same, or at the very least, is `dataList.size() >= list.size()` always true?

Comment: @L.Spillner yes, I want to retrieve the Id from each index in the list so I can pass it as a parameter in the next method call

Comment: @Pshemo We are using java 8 for the development, so it would be better if I could use stream instead.

Comment: What do you mean with “iterate n times”? There is only a single loop and it’s not even clear why you use an index based iteration instead of a plain `for(ElementType variableName: list) …`

Comment: What does "rest of the code" do?   It is important to know, because the "rest of the code" will determine whether it is a good idea to use Java 8 streams here.

Comment: @StephenC updated the ques for clarity

Comment: Based on your updates, I think that you will NOT make the code better by using Java 8+ streams.  Your existing version using a loop is just fine.   (Though a "for each" loop would be better.)

Comment: Since you only used `i` to redundantly evaluate `list.get(i)` twice, you could have used a for-each loop, e.g. `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); for(ElementType o: list) map.put(o.getUser(), getDetail(o.getId()).getBody().getData());`. Since the list’s element type is not recognizable from your posted code, you have to substitute `ElementType` for the actual list element type. But using a stream is also possible, `Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getUser(), o -> getDetail(o.getId()).getBody() .getData()));`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could change your snippet here to use Java-8 Streams.
Here an overview of a few straight out of my head.

```
List<IDWrapper> list = IntStream.range( 0, 20 ).mapToObj( IDWrapper::new ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    List<String> details = list.stream().map( IDWrapper::getId ).map( this::getDetails ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    List<String> details2 = list.stream().map( item -> item.getId() ).map( id -> getDetails( id ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    List<String> details3 = list.stream().map( item -> getDetails( item.getId() ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Let's break them down and explain their differences a bite more.

1.

```
List<String> details = list.stream().map( IDWrapper::getId ).map( this::getDetails ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

This one uses MethodReferences to pass the desired functions down the `Stream#map(Function)` method. It can be read as 'map the items, which are IDWrapper-Objects and do it by calling `IDWrapper#getId()` on every object and put the resulting items (integer values in this case) back into the stream'. Afterwards  another call to `Stream#map(Function)` is done but this time the object to operate on is 'this' (my dummy class i created for the example) and call the `#getDetails(int)` method on this class.

2.

```
List<String> details2 = list.stream().map( item -> item.getId() ).map( id -> getDetails( id ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

This one is quite simply equal to 1. but using usual lambda expression to achieve the same.

3.

```
List<String> details3 = list.stream().map( item -> getDetails( item.getId() ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

In this case we're defining the function as a lamda and simply chaining the method class.

As mentioned before there are lots of other possibilities, but here are an education few. Hope I could help you understanding streams a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Map<String,Integer> m =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getUser, // key extractor
                                  e -> getDetail(e.getId()).getBody().getData() // value extractor
                                 )
                );
```

----EDIT----

Ho ho... This is exactly Holger's comment. Give credit where credit is due.